# Hard drive boots, but asks to be formatted when attached to another computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, formatting

I am trying to cleanup a hard drive that has been infected.  I've done this hundreds of times for people, but am having an issue with this one.

The infected system is a Windows 7 install (Home Premium I think).  I am able to boot it into safe mode just fine, and all of the partitions show up just fine in Computer.

I then remove the hard drive from the machine and use an IDE/SATA to USB tool (that I have used countless times before) to attach it to my machine (Windows 7 Professional).

When I do this, Windows tells me that the drive needs to be formatted, and using the Disk Manager or other partition software, it cannot see the partitions on there.

Why would the machine boot up fine locally and show all of the partitions just fine, but when I attach it to another computer it appears that the MBR or the partitions are corrupt?

EDIT: Also want to note that when I plug this into a Ubuntu machine, it too cannot read the partitions properly (can't detect all of them or the filesystem types of the ones it can find).  I find this also very odd as like I said, when I actually boot the machine with the hard drive in it, it works and the partitions can be accessed without issue.  For some reason other machines cannot see these partitions though.

Comment: What size is the hdd?

Comment: I believe that it is 640GB.